# My scroll view does't shows the last relative layout

Tags: android, scrollview

When I scroll my contents the last `RelativeLayout` cannot be shown in the `Activity`. I have a `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView` . The `LinearLayout` have many `RelativeLayout`'s (I have shown only one) with views. Now the problem is the last `RelativeLayout` does't appears when I scroll down.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/thursday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Thursday" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTime6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:text="Time" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/friday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Friday" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTime7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:text="Time" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Add the complete code.

Comment: you have any editfield or button is there in bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please remove

```
  android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
```

from `LinearLayout`.

if you want to gap between `ActionBar` to your List add margin top to `ScrollView`